# Links displays in blue in gmail

Tags: html, css, gmail, mailchimp

When I add following code to MailChimp editor it display me correct version, but after sending  test email all links become blue.

```
    <span><a href="mailto:info@mysite.com" target="_top" style="text-decoration:none;">info@mysite.com</a></span>
        <span style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px">|</span>
        <span><a href="*|UNSUB|*" style="text-decoration:none;">Unsubscribe</a></span>
    </span>
```

What is interesting that gmail show links blue, but google inbox show correct version.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try to specfiy color to the anchor tags <a href="mailto:info@mysite.com" target="_top" style="text-decoration:none;color:blue;"  . <a href="*|UNSUB|*" style="text-decoration:none;color:blue;"

Comment: @HemaNandagopal thanks! it works!

Comment: Welcome :) Don't forget to upvote :D

Answer (score 1):

Make anchor tag css as follows

```
<style>
  a {
    color: #000000!important; // Black
  }
</style>
```

Change the anchor tag color to whatever you want.